# Line break issue with high number of badges/rep

Tags: bug

Just looking at an older question I noticed Darin's rep badge, I wondered what the lonesome 2401 was about.

[image]

After hovering on it - It showed "bronze badges"

[image]

Just thought maybe a quick fix for alignement would be to convert badge totals into `k` values.

e.g. `699k 163 2.5k 2.4k`

And would fit on one line.
Or group the badge and number so it line breaks together.

Comment: So it's been answered twice, technically? But not really a big enough issue to fix, unless you got OCD like me :D

Comment: You know you've got OCD when you want to start calling it CDO just so it's in the right order :p

Comment: Now you got my blood flowing... :D

Comment: Finally! A rep formatting bug that doesn't involve Jon Skeet!